# What protocol does the data wire on an EV charger use?

Tags: communication, automotive, charger, charging

I recently installed [an EV charger](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09ZNN3JB7) and noticed that there is a low voltage data wire to the car in addition to the high voltage charging wires.

- What is the protocol that is used to communicate on the blue wire pictured below?
- What data is communicated to or from the vehicle?

[image: Emporia EV Charger Connector]

Comment: SAE J1772  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAE_J1772)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In addition to the duty cycle determining the max amperage that the car can draw, there is a simple signaling protocol between the EVSE and the car which controls when the EVSE can apply AC voltage to the plug.

Basically, the EVSE produces a 1 kHz square wave at +12V into an open circuit when the car is not connected. When the car is plugged in, the car has a 2.74 kΩ resistor to ground which drops the voltage to ~9 V. When the car is ready to charge, it adds a parallel 1.3 kΩ resistor which drops the voltage to ~6 V. In addition, the EVSE can signal an error state by asserting -12 V. This is discussed in [(Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAE_J1772#Control_Pilot).

The duty cycle of the 1 kHz pilot signal determines the maximum current the car is allowed to draw:

[image]

This is discussed in the same Wikipedia section (and the above table is from there).

Comment: Maybe also have a look at https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/237794/154343